# Django app with uwsgi, nginx: "no module called site"

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx

I am setting up a django application using nginx, uwsgi, and a virtual environment. I am using python version 2.7.12 and ubuntu 16.04. When I visit my server's IP address, I get the nginx welcome page. However, when I visit my website's domain name I get a 502 bad gateway error. I am following the steps from [DigitalOcean's guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Here is the output from **sudo systemctl status uwsgi**:

```
● uwsgi.service - uWSGI Emperor service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-06-24 05:06:46 UTC; 7min ago
Process: 11650 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown django:www-data /run/uwsgi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 11655 (uwsgi)
Status: "The Emperor is governing 0 vassals"
CGroup: /system.slice/uwsgi.service
       └─11655 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites

Jun 24 05:13:56 localhost uwsgi[11655]: lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Jun 24 05:13:56 localhost uwsgi[11655]: thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Jun 24 05:13:56 localhost uwsgi[11655]: uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /home/django/firstsite/firstsite.sock fd 3
Jun 24 05:13:56 localhost uwsgi[11655]: setuid() to 1000
Jun 24 05:13:56 localhost uwsgi[11655]: Python version: 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Jun 24 05:13:56 localhost uwsgi[11655]: Set PythonHome to /home/django/Env/firstsite
Jun 24 05:13:56 localhost uwsgi[11655]: ImportError: No module named site
Jun 24 05:13:56 localhost uwsgi[11655]: VACUUM: unix socket /home/django/firstsite/firstsite.sock removed.
Jun 24 05:13:56 localhost uwsgi[11655]: Sat Jun 24 05:13:56 2017 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance firstsite.ini (pid: 11753)
Jun 24 05:13:59 localhost uwsgi[11655]: Sat Jun 24 05:13:59 2017 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance firstsite.ini
```

One error that seems to be part of the problem is: 
    Jun 24 04:30:55 localhost uwsgi[11155]: ImportError: No module named site
    Jun 24 04:30:55 localhost uwsgi[11155]: VACUUM: unix socket /run/uwsgi/firstsite.sock removed.

This is my firstsite.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
project   = firstsite
uid       = django
base      = /home/%(uid)

chdir     = %(base)/%(project)
home      = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module    = %(project).wsgi:application

master    = true
processes = 5

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(uid):www-data
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum    = true
```

When I run the command **sudo tail -F /var/log/nginmx/error.log**, this is the output:

```
2017/06/24 14:54:06 [crit] 11909#11909: *81 connect() to unix:/home/django/firstsite/firstsite.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 12.345.678.910, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/django/firstsite/firstsite.sock:", host: "example.com"
```

(fyi: for this post, I replaced my site's domain name with example.com)

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com www.example.com;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/django/firstsite;
}

location / {
    include         uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/django/firstsite/firstsite.sock;
    }
}
```

I am unsure why the uwsgi process is unable to create a .sock file, and am unsure if it is because python cannot find the module called "site." I saw some people on stackoverflow identified this as a python version problem, so I reloaded my server with a fresh ubuntu install, verified that the steps for python 2 were those followed (to the letter) in the DigitalOcean guide, and proceeded from there.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I fear that I have made a small mistake but I've spent several hours banging my head against this wall to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issues:

```
Jun 24 05:13:56 localhost uwsgi[11655]: Set PythonHome to /home/django/Env/firstsite
```

The first issue is that I created a virtualenvironment called "myvirtualenv", which meant that the path "/home/django/Env/firstsite" was invalid. Changing the path to "home/django/Env/myvirtualenv" resolved part of the problem.

Second, following the guide as written (for Ubuntu 16.04) causes a slight python versioning issue. This line, from **/etc/uwsgi/sites/firstsite.ini**

```
home = %(base)/Env/firstsite
```

must be changed to...

```
home = %(base)/Env/myvirtualenv/
```

To set the python path correctly. Again, this is because I did not name my virtualenv as the same name as my django project. All this trouble over a simple naming issue. Of course, in retrospect, the error logs were plainly stating this issue the whole time - unfortunately, I didn't know enough about error log usage at the time to make sense of their output, so overall this was a good learning experience.

I hope this helps someone else out there who might overlook something trivial like this.